# php curl empty certinfo with certinfo set to 1

Tags: php, curl

Trying to get certinfo fails. Here is the code i'm using:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '../cacerts.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, '../cacerts.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

Even tho the `CERTINFO` is set to `1` the result is still an empty certinfo:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://example.com
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Any idea on what should i do to fix this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs:

> CURLOPT_CERTINFO
>
> TRUE to output SSL certification information to STDERR on secure transfers.
>
> Requires CURLOPT_VERBOSE to be on to have an effect.

So, add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

And then actually run the request to get output:

```
curl_exec($ch);
```

And then note that the output is sent to STDERR, not `curl_getinfo()`.

Comment: Hey Alex, i've added `VERBOSE` and executed before printing it out but the certinfo is still empty. Any clue? Thank you so much!

Comment: _"And then note that the output is sent to STDERR, not curl_getinfo()."_

Comment: Oh, my bad :D, how do i get access to STDERR and/or is there a way to actually make curl_getinfo populate that certinfo?

Comment: Run your script from the command line instead of via a web page and the output will just stream to the terminal.